# External drive installed internally shows as RAW, how to fix?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, external-hard-drive

I have (had) an external drive (Hitachi Touro Desk 2TB) that I have installed internally, plugged into the motherboard via a SATA cable.

The drive shows up in Windows, but cannot be accessed, as it is listed as a being in RAW format.

In Disk Manager, the drive shows as being split in two, with a G: volume, having approx. 240GB RAW. The rest is shown as 1630GB Unallocated.

How can I get access to the files on the RAW part?

I still have the enclosure, so I could re-assemble if need be, but I would like to be able to use the drive internally.

Comment: If the drive is showing as RAW when connected via SATA it could be because the data was encrypted from the enclosure or due to a problem with the file system. In this situation a recommend that you put the drive back in the enclosure and download all the data if it's accessible. Once you have the data you can connect the drive via SATA again and use Windows disk Management to re-format it. It's also a good idea to run the manufacturer testing tool, but only after you have recovered the data.

Comment: So there is no way what-so-ever to read the data without putting it back in the enclosure?

Comment: That really depends from the reason why Windows is not reading the partition. You could try booting a Live Linux CD to check if it would see something different. However if the data is important it might be   a better idea to consider using the services of a data recovery professional.